# If $M\subseteq Y$ subspace then $M=Y$, and a related surjection

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Problem** Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces. If $M$ is an open subspace of $Y$, then $M=Y$. Deduce that any open linear mapping $T:X\to Y$ is surjective.

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C})$. A convex set $A\subseteq X$ is called absorbing if for all $x\in X$ there exists $p>0$ such that $x\in pA$.

**What I did**: 1) First, need to prove that $Y\subseteq M$. Let $y\in Y$ be given. Since $M$ is open, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(0,\varepsilon)$ is a subset of $M$. It is easy to show that $B(0,\varepsilon)$ is convex. I will show that $B(0,\varepsilon)$ is absorbing, i.e. to show that there exists $p>0$ such that $y\in pB(0,\varepsilon)$. I am stuck this part (see below). Since $M$ is closed under multiplication by scalar, it implies that $pB(0,\varepsilon)\subseteq M$, i.e. $y\in M$. To show that an open mapping $T:X\to Y$ is surjective is really short and trivial, since $T(X)$ is an open subspace of $Y$.

(Absorbing:) Let $\varepsilon$ be as above. Let $\lambda\geq 0$. We know that $\lambda y\to 0$ as $\lambda\to 0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda\|y\|<\varepsilon$ for all $\lambda<\delta$. This shows that $y\in \lambda B(0,\epsilon)$ for all $\lambda<\delta$. If we put $\lambda =0$ and $\delta = p$, we done. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you need to prove that is $M$ is an open subspace of $Y$ then $M=Y$ or is it given?

Comment: @ShakedBader I want to prove the following claim "($M$ open subspace of $Y$) $\implies$ ($M=Y$)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the only thing you're missing is to show that $B(0,\epsilon)$ is absorbing.

Proof:
Let $0\neq y\in Y$ and define $p=\epsilon\frac{1}{2||y||}$ then $||py||=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, thus $py\in B(0,\epsilon)$. So obviously $y\in \frac {1}{p}B(0,\epsilon)$ and we've finished.

Notice that $\frac{1}{p}>0$.

Comment: Wow, nice choice of $p$. I'll think carefully about it. What do you think about the rest of my proof, including about the last problem?

Comment: The rest of the proof is great:)